# Where can I spend a peaceful and relaxing night at DEL airport?

Tags: airports, recommendations, new-delhi, air-india, del

I'm flying with Swiss to New Delhi (IGI Airport) and after a 7 hour layover, I have another domestic flight with Air India. Since the layover is during night time, I would like to relax at the airport, and if possible also get some sleep and a shower.

I have seen at the official airport site that there are several lounges accessible that offer these options, but it is very difficult to judge which of them I should choose. Furthermore, there are also some recommendation sites and the Internet and I have read parts of the comments, but the problem seem to be that there are so many parts of the airport that are somehow separated and for me, it's not clear which parts of the airport I can access when I arrive with an international flight in the middle of the night and leave in the morning with a domestic flight.

So my question is basically: Which lounge offers these options at the best price, and, is there also a option for free to get some sleep, such as very comfortable benches in a quiet area of the airport?

Comment: If it is terminal T3 you are saved. Is this the case?

Comment: I couldn't figure that out based on my flight information.

Comment: Air India, Indian Airlines, Jet Airways, Jet Lite, Jet Konnect & Kingfisher airlines departs & arrives at Terminal 3. In this case just hop on a inter-terminal bus and go to T3: http://www.newdelhiairport.in/inter-terminal-transfers.aspx

Comment: @Pixie Kingfisher doesnt exist anymore. ALso, international flights regardless of airline operate from T3

Comment: i got that from the airport´s website (see link in previous comment)! apologies for the wrong info if that´s the case...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The T3 Terminal is open throughout the night and you should easily be able to move around anywhere publicly accessible inside it. If you have a visa, you can just as easily go out. Since you mentioned you have a domestic flight, I'll assume you do have a visa. Unfortunately though, there is a lot of hustle and bustle due to international flight departures in the night as well. I doubt you will be able to find peace and quiet at the airport, but there are some options.

There isn't an answer which can suit everyone, but depending on your budget, there are some great options for hotels which are either inside the airport or offer a pickup service. Almost all of them offer free airport pickup service so it should be quite easy to get to them. Also, quick tip - Taxis in Delhi are not *very* expensive. Here's a list:

**I want something *at* the airport! (These options DO NOT require a Visa)**

Now doesn't this restrict your options a little bit. If you're not too concerned with services, wish to keep the price low *just* need a place to crash for a few hours, these are your best bet.

- [Plaza Premium Lounge](http://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g304551-d2403607-Reviews-Plaza_Premium_Lounge_International_Arrivals-New_Delhi_National_Capital_Territory_of_De.html)
- [Sam's Snooze at my Place](http://www.newdelhiairport.in/sleeping-pods-airport.aspx)
- **[Shower/Lounges at Delhi Airport](http://www.newdelhiairport.in/business-vip-facilities.aspx)**

The airport website offers some insight into the facilities. It also allows you to book only a shower at T3 Arrivals if you just prefer that (About $7). Be sure to check that out as well.

---

**5 Star Hotels - Expect anything greater than $100**

- **[Radisson Blu Plaza Delhi](http://www.booking.com/hotel/in/radisson-new-delhi.en-us.html)**
- [Holiday Inn New Delhi Airport](http://www.booking.com/hotel/in/holiday-inn-new-delhi-international-airport.en-us.html)
- [JW Marriott New Delhi Aerocity](http://www.booking.com/hotel/in/jw-marriott.en-us.html)

These 3 five stars are more or less in the same complex and are extremely popular among business traveller. If you want good service at a decent price, check out **Radisson Blu**.

---

**4 Star Hotels - Expect anything around $40 - $80**

- [Hotel Shanti Palace](http://www.booking.com/hotel/in/shanti-palace-new-delhi.en-us.html)
- **[Airport Hotel Le Seasons Aerocity New Delhi](http://www.booking.com/hotel/in/le-seasons-delhi.en-us.html)**
- [Eaton Smart New Delhi Airport](http://www.booking.com/hotel/in/eaton-smart-new-delhi-airport.en-us.html)

Le Seasons is in the same complex as the other five stars I mentioned, which makes it a good option. Shanti Palace is relatively better but I believe Le Seasons should offer a better experience due to the cleanliness around Aerocity. Also, it is relatively cheaper. I put Eaton on the list even though it's *inside* the airport, it is a legit hotel but it is absurdly expensive with sub-par service.

---

**3 Star Hotels - Expect anything around $20 - $50**

- [Hotel Chanakya Inn](http://www.booking.com/hotel/in/chanakya-inn.en-us.html)
- [Airport Hotel De Aura](http://www.booking.com/hotel/in/de-aura.en-us.html)
- **[Hotel Delhi Aerocity](http://www.booking.com/hotel/in/delhi-aerocity.en-us.html)**
- **[Hotel Ibis Delhi Airport](http://www.ibis.com/gb/hotel-7484-ibis-delhi-airport/index.shtml)**

This is a tough cookie, but I would suggest either Delhi Aerocity or De Aura. Whichever is cheaper for the date you find it at. Ibis is relatively new in the area so it does have good services, but higher prices.

Answer (score 3):

*The Guide to Sleeping in Airports* has [an entry on DEL](http://www.sleepinginairports.net/asia/delhi.htm).

Comment: It's not encouraging… (+1 for the link but your answer would be even better if you could summarize the most salient points).

Comment: I had no idea there was a guide to sleeping in airports. But honestly it does *not* seem well maintained. :( At least not for the Delhi airport. A summary would still be lovely though!

Comment: Yeah, it's not perfect at all; it's completely reliant on user-submitted comments, it seems. Hopefully somebody can give a better answer. If somebody reads the comments to extract the most important points they can also make a better answer.

Comment: I have read parts of the comments, but the problem seem to be that there are so many parts of the airport that are somehow separated and for me, it's not clear which parts of the airport I can access when I arrive with an international flight in the middle of the night and leave in the morning with a domestic flight.

Comment: Your int'l flight will definitely arrive in T3, and unless you're continuing on a LCC (Spicejet, Indigo, GoAir), your domestic flight will also be from T3.

Answer (score 2):

[SAMS SNOOZE AT MY SPACE](http://www.newdelhiairport.in/sleeping-pods-airport.aspx) may be what you are looking for. Be advised though. IGI Airport like all airports in India restricts passenger movement. Some areas are strictly meant for international transfers only.

Also, check out IGI's [Aiport Hotel](http://www.newdelhiairport.in/eaton-smart.aspx).